# How can I read DateTime data type from .CSV file data with Julia

Tags: julia

How can I read DateTime from .CSV file data with Julia (julia version 1.0.1)?   If you notice here, when it reads in my data, its marked as "String" values but I was hoping the call to head() would show DateTime values as the data type.

I'm reading like this:

```
using Dates, CSV, DataFrames
dfmt = dateformat"yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss"
column_types = Dict(:pickup_datetime=>DateTime, :dropoff_datetime=>DateTime)
df = convert(DataFrame, CSV.read("$(Base.source_dir())/small_taxi.csv", 
  types=column_types, dateformat=dfmt))
function reduce_dataframe(data_frame)
  return data_frame[[:vendor_id, :pickup_datetime, :dropoff_datetime, 
    :passenger_count, :trip_distance]]
end
df = reduce_dataframe(df)
head(df)
```

Here is my program output (from taxi data):

```
julia> include("hello.jl")
Started ...
elapsed CPU time: 0.09325 seconds
  0.094642 seconds (548.85 k allocations: 10.445 MiB)
6×4 DataFrame
│ Row │ vendor_id │ pickup_datetime     │ dropoff_datetime    │ passenger_count │
│     │ Int64⍰    │ String⍰             │ String⍰             │ Int64⍰          │
├─────┼───────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1         │ 2017-01-01 01:21:25 │ 2017-01-01 01:51:56 │ 2               │
│ 2   │ 1         │ 2017-01-01 02:17:49 │ 2017-01-01 02:17:49 │ 3               │
│ 3   │ 1         │ 2017-01-01 02:30:02 │ 2017-01-01 02:52:56 │ 1               │
│ 4   │ 1         │ 2017-01-01 04:17:32 │ 2017-01-01 04:17:36 │ 1               │
│ 5   │ 1         │ 2017-01-01 04:41:54 │ 2017-01-01 05:24:22 │ 1               │
│ 6   │ 1         │ 2017-01-01 10:41:18 │ 2017-01-01 10:56:59 │ 2               │
```

What is the trick here?    Here is some sample data if you want to try yourself:  https://gist.github.com/djangofan/09c6304b55f2a73cb05d0d2afc7902b1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When faced with such conversion issues, it best to go a bit low level to understand what is going on.

So, we start by looking your date-time string from your tables

```
dt_str="2017-01-01 01:21:25"
```

Can it be formatted with our format string?

```
dfmt = dateformat"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
Date(dt_str,dfmt)
```

Running that we get

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: Unable to parse date time. Expected directive Delim( hh:) at char 11
```

Something is not quite right here. Lets consult the [manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/stdlib/Dates/#Constructors-1). The manual points to [Dates.DateFormat](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/stdlib/Dates/#Dates.DateFormat)  and tonnes of examples at [stdlib/Dates/test/io.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/stdlib/Dates/test/io.jl).

We notice that we have been using the wrong letters for months, hours and seconds. We test now

```
dfmt = dateformat"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS"
Date(dt_str,dfmt)
```

No errors this time! We try it on our table

```
t_data=CSV.read("$(Base.source_dir())/small_taxi.csv", dateformat=dfmt)
t_data[:vendor_id, :pickup_datetime, :dropoff_datetime, 
        :passenger_count, :trip_distance]
```

We get

```
julia> t_data[[:vendor_id, :pickup_datetime, :dropoff_datetime, 
               :passenger_count]]
5×4 DataFrame
│ Row │ vendor_id │ pickup_datetime     │ dropoff_datetime    │ passenger_count │
│     │ Int64⍰    │ DateTime⍰           │ DateTime⍰           │ Int64⍰          │
├─────┼───────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ 1   │ 2         │ 2017-09-23T05:08:42 │ 2017-09-23T05:27:39 │ 6               │
│ 2   │ 1         │ 2017-07-14T19:07:38 │ 2017-07-14T19:54:17 │ 1               │
│ 3   │ 2         │ 2017-10-29T00:42:06 │ 2017-10-29T00:43:12 │ 2               │
│ 4   │ 2         │ 2017-10-02T20:38:17 │ 2017-10-02T21:13:09 │ 1               │
│ 5   │ 1         │ 2017-05-11T22:53:11 │ 2017-05-11T23:27:53 │ 2               │
```

Comment: This worked.  Thanks.  It was just capitalization in the date formatter I was using.

Answer (score 3):

Libraries you need (often forgotten, which frustrates the learners).

```
# import Pkg; Pkg.add("CSV")
using CSV

# import Pkg; Pkg.add("Dates")
using Dates

# import Pkg; Pkg.add("DataFrames")
using DataFrames
```

The date format depends on the original data in CSV file.

Note below: 'u' stands for 3-letter English month, e.g. "Aug. 3, 2020"

```
date_format="yyyy.mm.dd" # or "yyyy-mm-dd" or "u. dd, yyyy"
```

Read DataFrame with formated date format outputting standard Date "yyyy-mm-dd"

```
df = CSV.read(        # returns DataFrame
        file_path,    # URL
        dateformat="$date_format"
        )
```

Example output:

```
82 rows × 4 columns

Date    ActualValue ForecastValue   PreviousValue
Date    Float64 Float64?    Float64?
1   2020-08-03  44.3    34.4    42.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that they changed the macro in Julia 1.0, so the dateformat statement form is

```
dfmt = @dateformat_str("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")
```

or

```
dfmt = dateformat"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS"
```

though I don't have your dated CSV file to verify this works.

(added when you edited question to give file) In addition, your provided file is tab separated with repeated tabs, so you need:

```
using Dates, CSV, DataFrames
dfmt = dateformat"yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss"
df = convert(DataFrame, CSV.read("$(Base.source_dir())/small_taxi.csv", 
    dateformat=dfmt, delim="\t", ignorerepeated=true))
function reduce_dataframe(data_frame)
    return data_frame[[:vendor_id, :pickup_datetime, :dropoff_datetime, 
        :passenger_count, :trip_distance]]
end
df = reduce_dataframe(df)
head(df)
```

Comment: I updated my question a little.  It didn't work, but I know I must still have a typo somewhere.  I included a link to my CSV sample file.

Comment: The CSV you link to has a lot of whitespace and is not comma separated. If you adjust for that, it works without the column_types part:  as df = convert(DataFrame, CSV.read("$(Base.source_dir())/small_taxi.csv", 
   dateformat=dfmt))

Comment: Corrected case of the time pert of the format as in latest answer--I was trying to get the CSV to load at all given the tabbed format and your original code.